# Java Hibernate. Creates record with error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

When I try to create Annotation record appears this error.

> org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved
>   transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing

**Annotation entity**

```
public class Annotation implements Identifiable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user")
    private User profile;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String description;

    // Only getters and setters

}
```

**User entity**

```
@Entity
@Table
@Component
public class User implements Identifiable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String username;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false,columnDefinition = "int default 1")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private UserRole role = UserRole.ROLE_USER;

    @Column
    private Boolean enabled = Boolean.TRUE;

}
```

I know for avoid this error I must use **CascadeType.ALL** but after that appears another problem: when I try to create Annotation record, automaticly creates User record that shouldn't.

How add id_profile in new annotation record?

Comment: I had similar issues, solved by following exactly what he did: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem by changing

```
@Column(name="id_user")
    private Long idUser;
```

instance of

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user")
    private User profile;
```

But I think this way is a wrong